# Custom typing definitions file is ignored after Upgrade to Angular 9

Tags: angular, webpack

First, the project was building perfectly when it was in V8.x, I didn.t changed any thing.

I called

`ng update @angular/cli --force` to update, the '--force' is only to bypass one package i.e. `angular-in-memory-web-api`

I have a definition file that contains some definition :

```
// *********** typings.d.ts

 /* SystemJS module definition */
declare var module: NodeModule;
interface NodeModule {
   id: string;
}

declare var KTMenu: any;
declare var KTOffcanvas: any;
declare var KTScrolltop: any;
declare var KTHeader: any;
declare var KTToggle: any;
declare var KTUtil: any;
declare var KTPortlet: any;
declare var KTDialog: any;
declare var KTWizard: any;
declare var Chart: any;



declare module "*.png" {
    const content: any;
   export default content;
}


declare module "*.html" {
   const content: any;
   export default content;
}

declare module "*.jpg" {
     const content: any;
   export default content;
 }

declare module "*.svg" {
   const content: any;
   export default content;
 }
```

the tsconfig

```
 // tsconfig.json

 {
        "compileOnSave": false,
        "compilerOptions": {
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true
    }
 }
```

the tscoconfig.app.json

```
 {
   "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
     "baseUrl": "./",
     "types": []
   },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
   ]
 }
```

the webpack.config

```
    /**
    * Main file of webpack config.
    * Please do not modified unless you know what to do
    */
    const path = require("path");
    const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
    const WebpackRTLPlugin = require("webpack-rtl-plugin");
    const WebpackMessages = require("webpack-messages");
    const del = require("del");

    // theme name
    const themeName = "metronic";
    // global variables
    const rootPath = path.resolve(__dirname);
    const distPath = rootPath + "/src/assets";

    const entries = {
      "css/style.angular": "./src/assets/sass/style.angular.scss"
    };

    // remove older folders and files
    (async () => {
       await del.sync(distPath + "/css", { force: true });
    })();

    const mainConfig = function () {
        return {
           mode: "development",
          stats: "errors-only",
          performance: {
             hints: false
         },
         entry: entries,
         output: {
                // main output path in assets folder
               path: distPath,
              // output path based on the entries' filename
               filename: "[name].js"
           },
          resolve: { extensions: ['.scss'] },
         plugins: [
               // webpack log message
                new WebpackMessages({
                   name: themeName,
                   logger: str => console.log(`>> ${str}`)
               }),
               // create css file
               new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                   filename: "[name].css",
                }),
                new WebpackRTLPlugin({
                   filename: "[name].rtl.css",
               }),
              {
                  apply: (compiler) => {
                        // hook name
                        compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('AfterEmitPlugin', (compilation) => {
                            (async () => {
                               await del.sync(distPath + "/css/*.js", { force: true });
                         })();
                        });
                    }
                },
            ],
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {//**
                        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|jp2|webp|svg)$/,
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        exclude: /node_modules/, 
                        options: {
                            name: 'media/[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    },
                    //{
                    //    test: /\.(mp4)$/i,
                    //    loader: "file-loader?name=/videos/[name].[ext]",
                    //    exclude: /node_modules/
                    //},
                    {
                        test: /\.scss$/,
                        use: [
                            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                            "css-loader",
                            {
                                loader: "sass-loader",
                              options: {
                                    sourceMap: true,
                                }
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            },
        }
    };

    module.exports = function () {
       return [mainConfig()];
    };
```

**The problem that all variables and modules defined in the `typings.d.ts` are not recognized and the build command keeps showing - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'KTUtil'**  — `KTUtil` is example

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Yes, hope coming reply will help, the short answer is there are some hidden exceptions due to the packages versions incompatibility that is wrongly interpreted as undefined global variables.

Comment: If you want a piece of clear evidence, try to locally declare the global vars in each file uses them and you will see the real errors. 
My advice is; if you are using some libraries or third party elements; to keep use them in the recommended  dependencies versions, bcs as you know ng9 is newly released and not all packages have updated their work to conform the v9

Comment: another point is, the v9 requires the utilization of the ts v 3.7.x so in addition to the previous point, packages have to also revamp new releases following the v3.7.x of ts.
Hope this helpful

Answer (score 6):

I've got the same issue when I migrate to Angular 9.

I fix it just adding ***typings.d.ts*** in your `tsconfig.app.json`

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "types": []
    },
    "files": ["main.ts", "polyfills.ts"],
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "typings.d.ts"]
}
```

Comment: This fixed my issue and should be marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are some hidden exceptions due to the packages versions incompatibility that is wrongly interpreted as undefined global variables

If you want a piece of clear evidence, try to locally declare the global vars in each file uses them and you will see the real errors. My advice is; if you are using some libraries or third party elements; to keep using them in the recommended dependencies versions, bcs as you know ng9 is newly released and not all packages have updated their work to conform the v9
another point is, the v9 requires the utilization of the ts v 3.7.x so in addition to the previous point, packages have to also revamp new releases following the v3.7.x of ts. Hope this helpful